# codename one simulator skin

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

I cannot change the phone skin on the simulator. Whenever I download a new skin from the skin drop down menu, it says it was downloaded yet I do not see it on the skin drop down menu. When I try to go download it again, it is not there. I need to simulate it on a specific phone.

Windows 10 and using Eclipse with a Codename 1 project.

Comment: On what OS and IDE is this happening?

Comment: Windows 10 and I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

In Codename One Settings go to `Basic` -> `Update Client Libs` and restart the simulator.

Comment: I managed to update client libs but the same problem is still occurring. Every time I download a skin for the simulator, it disappears from the download list yet I am unable to select it. Only skins I can choose are the default Iphone3gs and desktop.

Comment: Is there an issue with your JavaSE preferences API? Which JDK are you using under which OS?

Comment: JDK 1.8.0_144 with windows 10. How would I check my JavaSE preferences API?

Comment: Make sure you are running as admin. Java usually prints an error when there is a failure to access the preferences API, look in the console in the IDE

Comment: Nothing changed while running as admin. No error is printed, the problem is that the skin does not appear as an option to switch to even after downloading it. I cannot change the simulator skin. Restarting the simulator and Eclipse does nothing. The eclipse console even says "Downloading xxxxxx bytes."

Comment: Check the `.codenameone` directory in your home directory and make sure the skin files are there. Open regedit and search for skin file names you should find them over there. Anything weird? Special characters or something out of the ordinary?

Comment: The skin files are there but still cannot select them. Here's how they are listed in the registry. "\/H/T/C10.skin    REG_SZ    8" and "\nexus.skin    REG_SZ    8" and "skin    REG_SZ    \iphone3gs.skin" with the other skins being similar.

Comment: If you just type the skin names separated by `;` does that show the menu? Maybe a character got corrupted and it all went to hell

Comment: There were a "skin" and a "skins" name in the registry. The "skin" is for the current skin for the simulator, which I can change and it will also change for the simulator. While the "skins" contain the default "\iphone3gs.skin" and a path that leads to the ".codenameone" folder containing the rest of the skins. I tried removing the file path and only including the name of the skins seperated by ";" but it does not work out.

Comment: I think we do need the full path there. Try using `Add Skin` and picking the files from there

Comment: That actually worked. I did not know where the skins where being downloaded to but your previous comments has showed it to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have any idea why this failed in your specific setup please file an issue in our issue tracker with that information. It should normally be seamless